# How are you supposed to start Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, cygwin, x11

I'm having a hard time trying to get my Cygwin installation of Tkinter to work. It seems so much more convoluted than any tutorial indicates, which makes me wonder whether I'm using it wrong.

Here is my "Hello, world" program.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import tkinter as tk

os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0'

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()
label = tk.Label(frame, text="Hey there.")
label.pack()
quitButton = tk.Button(frame, text="Quit", command=frame.quit)
quitButton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

So to run this program, I have to initialize X11, right? (Why is this part never mentioned in any tutorial?) So I installed X11 with Cygwin.

To initialize X11, I tried using the command "bash startxwin" in the console as indicated [here](http://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/using.html), but I just get the error "bad "add" command line"

So I used the command "xwin", which creates a huge black window. Running my program causes the window to [appear in the corner](http://imgur.com/J3ZkUuA). But I want it to appear in its own window.

This is apparently not the simple library I thought it was. It feels esoteric. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need X11 or Cygwin to use Tkinter – I've worked with Tkinter on Windows/some Unix-like systems (OS X, Ubuntu) without ever dealing with that. Try removing the `os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0'` line and see if it works properly – I've never seen/used that setting before.

Comment: Removing that line causes the "no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable" error.

Comment: Are you sure you need to be running this script on Cygwin, which is not an OS but rather what amounts to a simple Unix emulator that allows you to use Unix syntax and commands?

Comment: How did you install tinker ? Why you are not running X from the Menu ?

Comment: tkinter is a simple library. cygwin is not a simple way to run it. Is there a reason you have to run this via cygwin?

Comment: @MarquessofSalisbury How are you running this? Running it directly through Python should be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but it helped me solve this.  I am also on Windows 10.
You have to run a native X server. See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26555170/tcl-error-in-tkinter-when-launching-python-idle-from-cygwin) from @speaker-to-animals.
The os.environ command above is the same as SET DISPLAY=:0.0 from CMD.
Start the Xorg server on your Windows box, with no client, so it is waiting in the background.
With this setup, your code above works exactly as you want it to.  I ran it from the Windows CMD, not Cygwin.  I use this to add GUI to test cases - the testers like it.